# Azure Batch pools - use latest custom image for all new nodes

Tags: azure, azure-batch-account

I have an Azure Batch service with several pools.

Each pool autoscales, along with using a custom VM image from an image (compute) gallery.

As it stands, if the image version within the gallery updates, I have to:

- delete the pools
- create them again
- select the newest image version from the gallery for each node to use

Is there a way to configure the pools, so that all new nodes within the pools use the latest image version from the gallery - without having to recreate each pool? I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

The only documentation I can find to update a pool doesn't have any flags for updating the virtual machine configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/batch/pool?view=azure-cli-latest#az-batch-pool-set

**EDIT:**
I have found some documentation which implies that you can update the virtual machine configuration [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchmanagement/pool/update?tabs=HTTP#:%7E:text=KeyVault%20Extension%20instead.-,properties.deploymentConfiguration,Azure%20Cloud%20Services%20(PaaS)%2C%20while%20VirtualMachineConfiguration%20uses%20Azure%20Virtual%20Machines%20(IaaS).,-properties.displayName) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchmanagement/pool/update?tabs=HTTP#deploymentconfiguration)

Unfortunately, when I go to update this I receive the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "PropertyCannotBeUpdated",
    "message": "A property that cannot be updated was specified as part of the request.\nRequestId:the request id...",
    "target": "BatchAccount",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "Reason",
        "message": "A property that cannot be updated was specified as part of the request."
      },
      {
        "code": "PropertyName",
        "message": "deploymentConfiguration"
      },
      {
        "code": "PropertyPath",
        "message": "properties.deploymentConfiguration"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```